# pg_jit_available showing 'false' and jit not working, but config file seems set up properly

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, jit

I am trying to turn on JIT for testing purposes on a Postgresql 12 server, it was off before.
My postgresql.conf has the following properties activated (basically all default values):

- jit = on
- jit_above_cost = 100000
- jit_inline_above_cost=500000
- jit_optimize_above_cost=500000
- jit_provider = 'llvmjit'

I have also restarted the Postgres server service after editing the config.

Now when I run `show jit` I get `on`, however running `SELECT pg_jit_available()` returns `false`.
From the test queries I made it does not seem to include any JIT stuff happening in the query plan neither.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/jit-configuration.html) is a bit scarce on how configuration is done properly - is there anything I have missed about my setup?

Thanks!

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Does `pg_config` report that your version was compiled with JIT support?

Comment: The server is running on CentOS. I‘ll be away from my computer until tomorrow, but will check asap. Just in case it’s not obvious, where inside the `pg_config` would that info be found? Thank you!

Comment: In pg_config output, 'llvm' is probably the magic thing to look for.   `CONFIGURE =  ...'--with-llvm'...`  and `LDFLAGS = -L/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib ...`

Comment: `psql -c 'set client_min_messages TO debug1; select pg_jit_available();'` may also give some hints. If you are using the PGDG repository make sure you have installed `postgresql12-llvmjit`.

Comment: The command suggested by @Melkij returns `DEBUG:  probing availability of JIT provider at /usr/pgsql-12/lib/llvmjit.so
DEBUG:  provider not available, disabling JIT for current session`. Looks like the provider property in postgresql.conf alone doesn't suffice.

Also, the items @jjanes suggested do not appear inside `pg_config` output. I guess it will be necessary to reinstall the service with a version that includes jit support.